# splitting text file into array correctly with -split operator

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
      ;MPV_F4(isHold, taps, state)
      MPV_F5(isHold, taps, state)
         {
            if (taps == 1)
            {
                  if (isHold == 0)
                  {
                   ;[HV] T1 | cycle  mute | This is long LONG
                     Sendinput, {U+0398}  ;Θ ;   ;[rr] [cycle mute         ]
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    if (state)
                                          {
                                             while GetKeyState("f5", "p"){
                                                   Sendinput, {U+0399}  ;Ι ;   ;[rr] [add volume 10    ]  
                                                     sleep, 55
                                                 }  
                                          }
                          ; else
                          ;           {
                          ;           }
                  }
            }
         }      
      MPV_F6(isHold, taps, state)

      ;MPV_F7(isHold, taps, state)

      ;MPV_F8(isHold, taps, state)

      ;MPV_F9(isHold, taps, state)

      ;MPV_F11(isHold, taps, state)

      MPV_N2(isHold, taps, state)
         {
            if (taps == 1)
            {
                  if (isHold == 0)
                  {
                   ;[HV] T1 | cycle  mute | This is long LONG
                     Sendinput, {U+0398}  ;Θ ;   ;[rr] [cycle mute         ]
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    if (state)
                                          {
                                             while GetKeyState("f5", "p"){
                                                   Sendinput, {U+0399}  ;Ι ;   ;[rr] [add volume 10    ]  
                                                     sleep, 55
                                                 }  
                                          }
                          ; else
                          ;           {
                          ;           }
                  }
            }
         }
      ;MPV_N3(isHold, taps, state)
      ;MPV_N4(isHold, taps, state)
      ;MPV_N5(isHold, taps, state)
```

which essentially consists of a repeating pattern of:

```
FunctionName(isHold, taps, state)
{
 <Function Body>
}
```

I am trying to break it down into arrays that consists of the function name and body. I cant use the string ***MPV*** in my regex as there are other similar texts files whose function names does not contain  ***MPV***.
My exepected output is:

$MyVar [0] :

```
      MPV_F5(isHold, taps, state)
         {
            if (taps == 1)
            {
                  if (isHold == 0)
                  {
                   ;[HV] T1 | cycle  mute | This is long LONG
                     Sendinput, {U+0398}  ;Θ ;   ;[rr] [cycle mute         ]
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    if (state)
                                          {
                                             while GetKeyState("f5", "p"){
                                                   Sendinput, {U+0399}  ;Ι ;   ;[rr] [add volume 10    ]  
                                                     sleep, 55
                                                 }  
                                          }
                          ; else
                          ;           {
                          ;           }
                  }
            }
         }
```

$MyVar [1] :

```
      MPV_N2(isHold, taps, state)
         {
            if (taps == 1)
            {
                  if (isHold == 0)
                  {
                   ;[HV] T1 | cycle  mute | This is long LONG
                     Sendinput, {U+0398}  ;Θ ;   ;[rr] [cycle mute         ]
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    if (state)
                                          {
                                             while GetKeyState("f5", "p"){
                                                   Sendinput, {U+0399}  ;Ι ;   ;[rr] [add volume 10    ]  
                                                     sleep, 55
                                                 }  
                                          }
                          ; else
                          ;           {
                          ;           }
                  }
            }
         }
```

---

At first I tried to use ***Get-Content***'s `-Delimeter` parameter:

```
$mytextfile = "c:\temp\mytextfile.txt"
Get-content $mytextfile -Delimiter '.*[^;]\(isHold, taps, state\)'
```

It keeps returning the entire content as a single object, After a few more variations I resorted to just using `Get-Content -Raw` and then `-Split` operator:

```
$MyVar = $mytextfile -Split (?m).*[^;]\(isHold, taps, state\)(?s).*\}
```

I continue to get unexpected results, most commonly the entire content being returned instead of arrays.

I am using **RegEx101***, and options are closesly aligned to what powershell expects. I have tried many variations with no desired results.

Here is a link my [**RegEx101**](https://regex101.com/r/WOR1Xf/1) page.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Any help would be truelly wellcome.

Comment: Can you please reformat your code into a readable format?

Comment: @Zak, I made some changes, not entirely sure if thats what you meant though

Comment: [this](https://regex101.com/r/XeKxdH/1) regex might help you a bit. It's not a complete solution because it won't match the last function in the input, but otherwise it'll do.

Comment: @dc-ddfe this look really good. even as you say it being incomplete, it is a good example for me to build from. Thanks allot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$MyVar =
  [regex]::Matches(
    (Get-Content -Raw $mytextfile), 
    '(?sm)\w+\(isHold, taps, state\)\s*\{(?:.(?!\w+\(\w))+\}'
  ).Value
```

Note that this approach is computation-intensive and relies on detecting the end of a function not by properly detecting nested `{` / `}` pairs, but by assuming that the presence of any subsequent `<funcname>(<wordcharacter>` substring (e.g. `'MPV_F6(i'`) implies that the most recent `}` ended the function body.

See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/jfXUpV/3).

Comment: @mklement0 Fresh morning, fresh eyes! This works as expected and more. Strangely enough, I tried ommitting `MPV` from your RegEx and it still works as intended. This will serve as a good example to really go beyond a simple RegEx. Thanks allot!

Comment: @dc-ddfe, I misread your comment. I've updated the negative lookahead from `(?:.(?!MPV_))+` to `(?!\w+\(\w))+` to generalize it, which appears to work well enough for hellen_dorandt89, but, of course, it is no substitute for a language parsers that truly understands the file's syntax.

Comment: @hellen_dorandt89, glad to hear it. Please see the previous comment re generalizing the negative lookahead assertion. At least with your sample input, _omitting_ it doesn't work for me.